# How to handle multiple elements with the same class in laravel dusk

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

In my **dusk** test I want to firstly add and then delete news. Each news has *.delete-news* class but on the screen I have multiple elements. Each .delete-news class has in it's path data attribute with it's id *data-newsid="id"*. Now the browser does not know which delete-news class it should to click. How should I manage that?

Probably I should take delete-news class with the biggest data-newsid attribute. But I don't know how I should check it.

Currently I'm deleting it like this:

```php
public function testRemoveNews() {
    $this->browse(function ($browser) {
        $browser->visit('/')
                ->press('.delete_news')
                ->press('Yes')
                ->waitForText('News has been deleted!')
                ->press('OK')
                ->assertDontSee('Title of the news');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you sorting your news by `'id' desc`, maybe you should try

```php
->press('.delete-news:first') // or :nth-child(1)
```

or add a `dusk` attribute to first news element, like `dusk="last-news"`, and call it with:

```php
->press('@last-news')
```