# laravel dusk insert data into input array

Tags: php, laravel

hi im using laravel dusk 
and i have inputs as array like this ..

```
<input type='text' name='debits[]' />
<input type='text' name='debits[]' />
```

how can i add value to the first or second or specific input using the key of the array like

```
public function create(Browser $browser)
{
    $browser
    ->select('journal_id',1)
    ->pause(100)
    ->click('.add-line')
    ->click('.add-line')
    // code here to add 10 to first debits
    // code here to add 15 to second debits

    ;
}
```

is that possible thanks a lot ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283669/how-to-handle-multiple-elements-with-the-same-class-in-laravel-dusk suggests  using e.g. `array_name[]:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Can you push your code to GitHub? I mean the test part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```php
    $names = collect([
    
        'name1',
        'name2'
    
    ]);
    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($names) {
                $browser->visit('/names');
                $names->each(function ($name, $key) {
                  $browser->type("array[$key]", $name);
                });
                $browser->press('Send');
            });
```

Based on your code You can do this:

```php
public function create(Browser $browser)
{
    $browser
    ->select('journal_id',1)
    ->pause(100)
    ->click('.add-line')
    ->click('.add-line');
    
    $inputs = $browser->elements('input[name^="debits["]');
    $inputs[0]->sendKeys(10); // code here to add 10 to first debits
    $inputs[1]->sendKeys(15); // code here to add 15 to second debits
}
```

If you want to do it with a for loop you can do this:

```php
$inputs = $browser->elements('input[name^="debits["]');
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
  $input->sendKeys('100');
}
```

Comment: i gat this error  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body textarea[name='debits[0]']"}

Comment: but if i change the code like this ->type("debits[]", 1) its working for the first input only

Comment: I've updated my answer again so let me know if you have any question.